# Two tone style background

Tags: html, css

I just need to style two-tone color background like this.

I tried and successfully did using linear gradient

background: linear-gradient(172deg, #ECB034 50%, #BE883C 50%);

But it has a problem when resizing web page. It just not well aligned to its corners. Showing weirdly. Like this

[image]

is there any way to did this?

```css
.cta{
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(172deg, #ECB034 50%, #BE883C 50%);
  text-align:center;
}

.cta h3{
  font-size: 58px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a{
  padding: 16px 49px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
    <div class="cta text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Let’s talk about your project.</h3>
        <a href="">Get Started ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to share your markup to get any help. But I would suggest you use an SVG as the background image since the degrees needed to reach the corners will change as the aspect ration changes and SVG will be able to accomplish this feat without any extra math.

Comment: Hi! please upload HTML or site link

Comment: hi all pls check this fidddle https://jsfiddle.net/y0j1kc2n/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very simple fix with an SVG (as I mentioned in the comments) you simply need to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the SVG tag and run it through a URL encoder. [This one](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) will even generate the CSS for you which is quite nice.

```css
.cta{
  padding: 60px 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='100%25' width='100%25' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 10 10'%3E%3Crect width='10' height='10' fill='%23ECB034' /%3E%3Cpath d='m0 10 h10 v-10' fill='%23BE883C' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  text-align:center;
}

.cta h3{
  font-size: 58px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a{
  padding: 16px 49px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Let’s talk about your project.</h3>
        <a href="">Get Started ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything complex. Simply change the angle with `to bottom right`

```css
.cta{
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ECB034 50%, #BE883C 50%);
  text-align:center;
}

.cta h3{
  font-size: 58px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a{
  padding: 16px 49px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Let’s talk about your project.</h3>
        <a href="">Get Started ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **pseudo** and **clip-path** combination.

```css
.box{
  position:relative;
  background-color: #ecae20;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index:1;
}

.box .content{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #BE883C;
  clip-path: polygon(0 99%, 100% 0, 100% 99%, 0 100%);
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <p> Let's talk about your project </p>
    <button> GET STARTED > </button>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the angle needed changes with the aspect ratio it is not possible to do this with linear-gradient without some recalculation on every resize. (This is incorrect, see better suggestion from @temaniAfif using to bottom left etc.)

However, it is possible to create a triangle with its hypoteneuse being a diagonal by using clip-path and a polygon.

There is no need to inline an SVG if you put the two colors as backgrounds to the before and after pseudo elements, the after also having a clip-path.

```css
.cta {
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cta::before,
.cta::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cta::before {
  background-color: #ECB034;
}

.cta::after {
  background-color: #BE883C;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.cta h3 {
  font-size: 58px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a {
  padding: 16px 49px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Let’s talk about your project.</h3>
    <a href="">Get Started ></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pseudo` element for the same.

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  --container-width: 400px;
  --container-height: 200px;
  
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ecb034;
  height: var(--container-height);
  max-width: var(--container-width);
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  inset: auto 0 0 auto;
  border-bottom: var(--container-height) solid #be883c;
  border-left: var(--container-width) solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

**Make sure to keep `border-left-width` and `width` of the container same. And same for `height`.**